# Can Route Guards read data of Resolver?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I test in my app, I see that route guard is executed before resolver gets executed to read route related data from server, hence I can not read resolver data in guard.

Is there a way to read resolved data in guard, or this is how it supposed to be?

Sure I can create a service to read same data and use same service in guard and resolver. I just want to know about technical background.

Comment: I'd assume a resolver is only executed after a guard allowed to actually execute the route change, therefore I guess it's rather unlikely.

Comment: ^ This. That's chicken and egg situation. So a service is the way to go.

Comment: Related discussion on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15026). In short, the logic goes like *"Check if user can activate route (ex. has rights to enter) and if so, get (resolve) the data."*